# Android - Send Telegram,Whatsapp,etc multiple text by using share intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, line, whatsapp, telegram

Intent to send a telegram message

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
myIntent.setType("text/plain");
myIntent.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
mUIActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with"));
```

But this code shares a joint text like this(Separated by \n):
[image]

But I want the output to look like this.:
[image]

I thank any help.

**Edit 1:**
I think this is not possible :(
Telegram messenger use this method to forward multiple messages

```
private void forwardMessages(ArrayList<MessageObject> arrayList, boolean fromMyName) {
        if (arrayList == null || arrayList.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!fromMyName) {
            SendMessagesHelper.getInstance().sendMessage(arrayList, dialog_id, chatActivityEnterView == null || chatActivityEnterView.asAdmin());
        } else {
            for (MessageObject object : arrayList) {
                SendMessagesHelper.getInstance().processForwardFromMyName(object, dialog_id, chatActivityEnterView == null || chatActivityEnterView.asAdmin());
            }
        }
    }
```

This means that Telegram do not use share intent for multiple messages

This [Link](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/6bb7547f508d5d8effe8907f899adde95aeceb47/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/LaunchActivity.java#L611) in `handleIntent` method, The code is not intended for this work.[At this level :(]

Comment: as per the expected output, it looks like the output one will get on calling multiple intent share. where as the code you posted will get you one share with each text on new line which is as expected to do so, you might want to split the message string on \n and call the share intent on the new split string